# EGL_BAD_MATCH error Android Studio

Tags: android

I've just started a new project in Android Studio 2.2.
After I added some lines of code (mainly SQLite), I wanted to compile my masterpiece. And then, this occured:

> E/EGL_emulation: tid 3901: eglSurfaceAttrib(1146): error 0x3009
>   (EGL_BAD_MATCH)   W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on
>   surface 0xacfc9fa0, error=EGL_BAD_MATCH   Device
>   emulator-5554disconnected, monitoring stopped.   Application
>   terminated.

Does anyone know what's wrong? :)

Answer (score 10):

Go to the `TOOL -> android -> AVD Manager`, and change the settings of your device . Click the section `Emulated Performance` Graphics to Software GLSE 2.0.

[image]

Comment: Just noting - one may don't know - this will dramatically reduce AVD performance. In my case, the emulator seemed to be switched into a "slideshow" mode.

Answer (score 3):

go to the AVD Manager and change the settings of your device. E.g the on the section "Emulated Performance" -> Graphics to Hardware GLSE 2.0.

Greetings

Comment: Just tried this exactly but it does not work. Any other ideas?

Comment: I changed it to "Software GLSE 2.0" on my laptop and the error went away.

Comment: However I changed the settings to "Software GLSE 2.0" and it did work!

Comment: I'm using 2.2.3 and Nexus 6 API 24. I'm trying to use the debugger and I get this same error. I tried what you said but it didn't work. Then I changed it to Software and that didn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

version 3.1

Go to the TOOL -> AVD Manager, and change the settings of your device . Click the section Emulated Performance Graphics to Software GLSE 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your google login api is working correct. I was facing same issue caused by google log in integration.

Comment: Your package in you project at google API and your application package should be same. If you are checking google log in API just for testing you might have provided test package.

Answer (score 0):

Going to software mode is a pain. The Google Maps and Chrome app run just fine, so I dig a bit further.

For my case, it is because of the support libraries, in my Gradle, I had this:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1"
```

Which I changed to this, after Android Studio warned me that it might lead to crashes:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0'
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0"
```

And now the app runs fine.

Answer (score 0):

I got this in a Xamarin Forms application.  It was because at some point I received a compiler warning (which was wrong actually) that I didn't need 'override' keyword in my OnCreate method defintion in my MainActivity android project.  I foolishly took the keyword out and then I got this error.  So, keep the method definition like so:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
```