# EGL_BAD_MATCH in basic login activity

Tags: java, android

@Update
When i create new project everything its fine. But i don't know what is wrong. I just refactor all names with e-mail to login, change type of textview e-mail to normal.

---

I have problem with simple app. I made default loading activity. And change e-mail to login. So there will be login and password.

But app stop on device. There is error EGL_BAD_MATCH

Android monitor error

```
01-03 18:43:35.591 4738-4757/com.example.rachel.safemessenger E/EGL_emulation: tid 4757: eglSurfaceAttrib(1174): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)

01-03 18:43:35.591 4738-4757/com.example.rachel.safemessenger W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x923a4660, error=EGL_BAD_MATCH
```

Please help.

LoginActivity.java

```
package com.example.rachel.safemessenger;

import android.animation.Animator;
import android.animation.AnimatorListenerAdapter;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks;

import android.content.CursorLoader;
import android.content.Loader;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;

import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static android.Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS;

/**
 * A login screen that offers login via email/password.
 */
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>
{

    /**
     * Id to identity READ_CONTACTS permission request.
     */
    private static final int REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS = 0;

    /**
     * A dummy authentication store containing known user names and passwords.
     * TODO: remove after connecting to a real authentication system.
     */
    private static final String[] DUMMY_CREDENTIALS = new String[]{
            "foo@example.com:hello", "bar@example.com:world"
    };
    /**
     * Keep track of the login task to ensure we can cancel it if requested.
     */
    private UserLoginTask mAuthTask = null;

    // UI references.
    private AutoCompleteTextView mLoginView;
    private EditText mPasswordView;
    private View mProgressView;
    private View mLoginFormView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        // Set up the login form.
        mLoginView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.activityLogin_login);
        populateAutoComplete();

        mPasswordView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.activityLogin_password);
        mPasswordView.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int id, KeyEvent keyEvent)
            {
                if (id == R.id.login || id == EditorInfo.IME_NULL)
                {
                    attemptLogin();
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        Button mLoginSignInButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.activityLogin_name_sign_in_button);
        mLoginSignInButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                attemptLogin();
            }
        });

        mLoginFormView = findViewById(R.id.activityLogin_login_form);
        mProgressView = findViewById(R.id.activityLogin_login_progress);
    }

    private void populateAutoComplete()
    {
        if (!mayRequestContacts())
        {
            return;
        }

        getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
    }

    private boolean mayRequestContacts()
    {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        {
            return true;
        }
        if (checkSelfPermission(READ_CONTACTS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            return true;
        }
        if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(READ_CONTACTS))
        {
            Snackbar.make(mLoginView, R.string.permission_rationale, Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
                    .setAction(android.R.string.ok, new View.OnClickListener()
                    {
                        @Override
                        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
                        public void onClick(View v)
                        {
                            requestPermissions(new String[]{READ_CONTACTS}, REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);
                        }
                    });
        } else
        {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{READ_CONTACTS}, REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Callback received when a permissions request has been completed.
     */
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                           @NonNull int[] grantResults)
    {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS)
        {
            if (grantResults.length == 1 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            {
                populateAutoComplete();
            }
        }
    }


    /**
     * Attempts to sign in or register the account specified by the login form.
     * If there are form errors (invalid email, missing fields, etc.), the
     * errors are presented and no actual login attempt is made.
     */
    private void attemptLogin()
    {
        if (mAuthTask != null)
        {
            return;
        }

        // Reset errors.
        mLoginView.setError(null);
        mPasswordView.setError(null);

        // Store values at the time of the login attempt.
        String login = mLoginView.getText().toString();
        String password = mPasswordView.getText().toString();

        boolean cancel = false;
        View focusView = null;

        // Check for a valid password, if the user entered one.
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(password) && !isPasswordValid(password))
        {
            mPasswordView.setError(getString(R.string.error_invalid_password));
            focusView = mPasswordView;
            cancel = true;
        }

        // Check for a valid login address.
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(login))
        {
            mLoginView.setError(getString(R.string.error_field_required));
            focusView = mLoginView;
            cancel = true;
        } else if (!isLoginValid(login))
        {
            mLoginView.setError(getString(R.string.error_invalid_login));
            focusView = mLoginView;
            cancel = true;
        }

        if (cancel)
        {
            // There was an error; don't attempt login and focus the first
            // form field with an error.
            focusView.requestFocus();
        } else
        {
            // Show a progress spinner, and kick off a background task to
            // perform the user login attempt.
            showProgress(true);
            mAuthTask = new UserLoginTask(login, password);
            mAuthTask.execute((Void) null);
        }
    }

    private boolean isLoginValid(String login)
    {
        //TODO: Replace this with your own logic
        return login.contains("@");
    }

    private boolean isPasswordValid(String password)
    {
        //TODO: Replace this with your own logic
        return password.length() > 4;
    }

    /**
     * Shows the progress UI and hides the login form.
     */
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2)
    private void showProgress(final boolean show)
    {
        // On Honeycomb MR2 we have the ViewPropertyAnimator APIs, which allow
        // for very easy animations. If available, use these APIs to fade-in
        // the progress spinner.
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2)
        {
            int shortAnimTime = getResources().getInteger(android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime);

            mLoginFormView.setVisibility(show ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
            mLoginFormView.animate().setDuration(shortAnimTime).alpha(
                    show ? 0 : 1).setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter()
            {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation)
                {
                    mLoginFormView.setVisibility(show ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
                }
            });

            mProgressView.setVisibility(show ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
            mProgressView.animate().setDuration(shortAnimTime).alpha(
                    show ? 1 : 0).setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter()
            {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation)
                {
                    mProgressView.setVisibility(show ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
                }
            });
        } else
        {
            // The ViewPropertyAnimator APIs are not available, so simply show
            // and hide the relevant UI components.
            mProgressView.setVisibility(show ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
            mLoginFormView.setVisibility(show ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int i, Bundle bundle)
    {
        return new CursorLoader(this,
                // Retrieve data rows for the device user's 'profile' contact.
                Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Profile.CONTENT_URI,
                        ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.CONTENT_DIRECTORY), ProfileQuery.PROJECTION,

                // Select only email addresses.
                ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.MIMETYPE +
                        " = ?", new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email
                .CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE},

                // Show primary email addresses first. Note that there won't be
                // a primary email address if the user hasn't specified one.
                ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.IS_PRIMARY + " DESC");
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> cursorLoader, Cursor cursor)
    {
        List<String> logins = new ArrayList<>();
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast())
        {
            logins.add(cursor.getString(ProfileQuery.ADDRESS));
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }

        addLoginsToAutoComplete(logins);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> cursorLoader)
    {

    }

    private void addLoginsToAutoComplete(List<String> loginAddressCollection)
    {
        //Create adapter to tell the AutoCompleteTextView what to show in its dropdown list.
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =
                new ArrayAdapter<>(LoginActivity.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, loginAddressCollection);

        mLoginView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }


    private interface ProfileQuery
    {
        String[] PROJECTION = {
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.IS_PRIMARY,
        };

        int ADDRESS = 0;
        int IS_PRIMARY = 1;
    }

    /**
     * Represents an asynchronous login/registration task used to authenticate
     * the user.
     */
    public class UserLoginTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>
    {

        private final String mLogin;
        private final String mPassword;

        UserLoginTask(String login, String password)
        {
            mLogin = login;
            mPassword = password;
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params)
        {
            // TODO: attempt authentication against a network service.

            try
            {
                // Simulate network access.
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                return false;
            }

            for (String credential : DUMMY_CREDENTIALS)
            {
                String[] pieces = credential.split(":");
                if (pieces[0].equals(mLogin))
                {
                    // Account exists, return true if the password matches.
                    return pieces[1].equals(mPassword);
                }
            }

            // TODO: register the new account here.
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success)
        {
            mAuthTask = null;
            showProgress(false);

            if (success)
            {
                finish();
            } else
            {
                mPasswordView.setError(getString(R.string.error_incorrect_password));
                mPasswordView.requestFocus();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled()
        {
            mAuthTask = null;
            showProgress(false);
        }
    }
}
```

activity_login.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.rachel.safemessenger.LoginActivity">

    <!-- Login progress -->
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/activityLogin_login_progress"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/activityLogin_login_form"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/activityLogin_name_login_form"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/activityLogin_login"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/prompt_email"

                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:singleLine="true" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/activityLogin_password"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/prompt_password"
                    android:imeActionId="@+id/login"
                    android:imeActionLabel="@string/action_sign_in_short"
                    android:imeOptions="actionUnspecified"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:singleLine="true" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/activityLogin_name_sign_in_button"
                style="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:text="@string/action_sign_in"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

strings.xml

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">SafeMessenger</string>

    <!-- Strings related to login -->
    <string name="prompt_email">Nick</string>
    <string name="prompt_password">Password </string>
    <string name="action_sign_in">Sign in or register</string>
    <string name="action_sign_in_short">Sign in</string>
    <string name="error_invalid_login">This login is invalid</string>
    <string name="error_invalid_password">This password is too short</string>
    <string name="error_incorrect_password">This password is incorrect</string>
    <string name="error_field_required">This field is required</string>
    <string name="permission_rationale">"Contacts permissions are needed for providing email
        completions."
    </string>
</resources>
```

Comment: Please share your code inline.

Comment: What is it? Im a newbie.

Comment: I mean put the code inside the question and not in external tool. Have a look at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216464/how-to-insert-code-properly-on-stack-overflow

Comment: done. Could you help?

Comment: likely are showing completely irrelevant log, can you look for any exceptions there?

Comment: It is probably an issue related to your emulator configuration and not your code. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40566645/egl-bad-match-error-android-studio?rq=1

Comment: No, I change that - still the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, now it works. I think somehow to correct without my participation.

I update android devices and reset computer and now it works.